# Calling Jquery plugin for single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have called a Jquery plugin for Custom right click in the beginning of the html page.

```
<link href="css/context.standalone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/context.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo-context-menu.js"></script>
```

My problem is, the plugin is working fine everywhere i right-click on the window..
But i need my custom right click to be enabled only for a particular "div" so that if i click out of that div, default context-menu should popup(not my customized popup).
Sample code of the container is here:

```
/*demo-context-menu.js*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    context.init({preventDoubleContext: false});

    context.attach('body', [
    //  {header: 'Download'},
        {text: 'View'},
        {text: 'Add'},
        {divider: true},
        //{header: 'Meta'},
        {text: 'Delete'},
        {text: 'Clear', subMenu: [
            {text: 'Clear All'}
        ]}
    ]);
});
```

How should i achieve this? can someone help me? pls
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some normal code into your post

Comment: The only thing I see here is a bunch of libraries being loaded.

Comment: Look into API document of plugins.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put these lines of code on your page, they will be loaded for the whole page. You need to differenciate the behavior from within your jquery code, by checking in which div the right-click has been done.

Comment: you can use jquery .not() selector

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes are you seeing something here that nobody else can?

Comment: Somewhere in your code the plugin is being attached to an element. Where's this part of the code? If we can't see it, we can't help you.

Comment: No @MelanciaUK just giving some suggestion to user2759218

Comment: i have added the sample code. pls check that.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid you just included the HTML markup. We need to see the Javascript/jQuery/plugin code.

Comment: i have not added any code regarding the plugin anywhere in my page. thats what im asking. even if i dont add any code in html, it is working fyn. where should i include code so that it will work only in the div?

Comment: That's the point. How can we guess? We don't even know which plugin is this. Is it this one? http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html

Comment: Include the code from `context.js` and `demo-context-menu.js` into your question.

Comment: check now. i have taken the plugin from here [link]https://github.com/jakiestfu/Context.js

Comment: Just change `context.attach('body'` by replacing `body` with the container you want (CSS/jQuery selector).

Comment: No problems. Next time, so you can have a proper response easily, try to put as much (relevant) information as possible in your question. Include code, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo.js script that the plugin page uses demonstrates the usage:

http://lab.jakiestfu.com/contextjs/demo.js

```
context.attach('.inline-menu', [
    {header: 'Options'},
    {text: 'Open', href: '#'},
    {text: 'Open in new Window', href: '#'},
    {divider: true},
    {text: 'Copy', href: '#'},
    {text: 'Dafuq!?', href: '#'}
]);
```

Note that `.inline-menu` class is on an `a` tag in the plugin page.

Comment: thank you. i have replaced the .inline-menu with the class name of the container

Comment: I just saw all the comments above you should ask @MelanciaUK to post his comment as an answer and award to him. I didn't see his answer before I posted this and he got in first :)

Comment: That's OK. It was just a small detail, so I decided to leave it as just a comment.